# How to copy a webpage's text with code in PHP

Tags: php

I want to copy a page's **text** into a PHP variable.
I use `file_get_contents(...)` method but it doesn't work for my address
for example my address is:

http://www.bankmellat.ir/3/Default/94/1/Default/2/875/1/201.aspx?itemid=201

but this code not show the text of this page:

```
$filename='http://www.bankmellat.ir/3/Default/94/1/Default/2/875/1/201.aspx?itemid=201';
$homepage =  file_get_contents($filename , false);
echo ($homepage);
```

Comment: What output do you get? Any errors?

Comment: Try adding this in <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Rohit Awasthi : not worked!

Comment: trizz : not any error but it not display any text

Comment: @Sadegh , See, Try either $filename='http://www.bankmellat.ir/Public/11/Skins/Images/default/portal.css'; Or
$filename='http://www.facebook.com'; if anyof these works, then your code is correct.

Comment: these addresses work well

Comment: As facebook.com actually returns different webpage, just like that this website is also actually returning different webpage.If you see pagesource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most hosting provides now block the `furl_open` parameter which allows you to use `file_get_contents()` to load data from an external url.

Use this code:

```
<?php
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

// INIT CURL
$ch = curl_init();

//init curl 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

// SET URL FOR THE POST FORM LOGIN
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.bankmellat.ir/3/Default/94/1/Default/2/875/1/201.aspx?itemid=201');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

// common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Optional: Return the result instead of printing it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$store = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $store;

// CLOSE CURL
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

enjoy!!

Comment: I should use this code instead of the URL? it errors that CURL is an Undefined function!

Comment: thank you very much ;)
this code works well on server but it errors on "curl_init()" method in localhost.
do you have any idea?